# Asignar una clase a otra en ArrayList en java?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de una galeria de arte en java pero estoy estancado en algo. Tengo una clase para la obra, otra para el artista, otra para el cliente y otra para compras. Entonces primero debo de asignar obras a artistas para que se sepa quien es el autor de la obra, tnego un arraylist de obras y otro de artistas.

Lo mismo me pasa para hacer una compra, debo ingresar el codigo del cliente y el codigo de la obra para asignar la compra de la obra al cliente y generar un codigo de compra aleatorio pero de nuevo no se como hacer esta asignacion.

he tratado de hacer la lista de compras como un arraylist de tipo object, aca está el codigo completo:

```
public class PantallaGaleria {
    ControlGaleria control=new ControlGaleria();
        Obra obra=new Obra();
        Cliente cliente=new Cliente();
        Compra compra=new Compra();
        int op;
        long codigoObra;
        long codigoCliente;
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        public void Menu(){
            control.Instancias();
            control.InstanciasCliente();
            while(op<15){
            System.out.println("size: "+control.getListaobras().size());
            System.out.println("MENU\n");
            System.out.println("1.Ver obras disponibles\n");
            System.out.println("2.Buscar obra\n");
            System.out.println("3.Insertar obra\n");
            System.out.println("4.Modificar obra\n");
            System.out.println("5.Eliminar obra\n");
            System.out.println("6.Ver clientes registrados\n");
            System.out.println("7.Buscar cliente\n");
            System.out.println("8.Insertar cliente\n");
            System.out.println("9.Modificar datos de cliente\n");
            System.out.println("10.Eliminar cliente\n");
            System.out.println("11.Comprar obra\n");
            System.out.println("12.Eliminar compra\n");
            System.out.println("13.Ver listado de compras\n");
            System.out.println("14.Ver artistas más vendidos\n");
            System.out.println("15.Salir\n");
            System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion: ");
            op=scan.nextInt();
            
            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    control.VerListaObras();
                    break;
                    
                case 2:

                    break;
                    
                case 3:
                    for (int i=0;i<1;i++) {
                        control.InsertarObra(obra);
                    }
                    //control.AsignarObraArtista(obra);
                    break;
                    
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese codigo de la obra a modificar: ");
                    codigoObra=scan.nextLong();
                    control.ModificarObra(codigoObra);
                    break;
                    
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese codigo de la obra a eliminar: ");
                    codigoObra=scan.nextLong();
                    control.EliminarObra(codigoObra);
                    break;
                    
                case 6:
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 7:
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 8:
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 9:
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 10:
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 11:
                    control.ComprarObra(codigoObra,codigoCliente,compra,obra,cliente);
                    break;
                    
                case 12:
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 13:
                    control.VerListaCompras();
                    break;
                    
                case 14:
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 15:
                    System.out.println("Presione cualquier tecla para salir");
                    break;
                    
                default:System.out.println("Opcion invalida");
            }
          } 
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PantallaGaleria mn=new PantallaGaleria();
        mn.Menu();
    }
}

public class GestionObras {
    Obra obra1=new Obra(1234567,"Cielo",(new GregorianCalendar(2000, 8, 31)),300000,"20x40 cm");
    Obra obra2=new Obra(1234568,"Mona Lisa",(new GregorianCalendar(1876, 2, 29)),320000,"60x50 cm");
    Artista art1=new Artista(2083741,1928734793,"Jean","Melunier",(new GregorianCalendar(1950,2,23)),3495872);
    Artista art2=new Artista(3982710,1947262946,"Leonardo","Dicaprio",(new GregorianCalendar(1978,7,11)),3048586);
    ArrayList<Obra> obras=new ArrayList<Obra>();
    ArrayList<Artista> artistas=new ArrayList<Artista>();
    
    public ArrayList AgregarObras(){
       obras.add(obra1);
       obras.add(obra2);
       return obras;
    }
    
    public ArrayList AgregarArtistas(){
        artistas.add(art1);
        artistas.add(art2);
        return artistas;
    }
}

public class GestionClientes {
    Cliente cliente1=new Cliente(1111111,18156052,"andres","rincon alfonso","cll fake 123",3123545);
    ArrayList<Cliente> clientes=new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    public ArrayList AgregarClientes(){
       clientes.add(cliente1);
       return clientes;
    }
}

public class Obra {
    private long codigoObra;
    private String titulo;
    private Calendar fecha;
    private float precioRef;
    private String dimensiones;

    public Obra() {
    }

    public Obra(long codigoObra, String titulo, Calendar fecha, float precioRef, String dimensiones) {
        this.codigoObra = codigoObra;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.precioRef = precioRef;
        this.dimensiones = dimensiones;
    }
    
    public Obra(Obra obra) {
        this.codigoObra = obra.getCodigoObra();
        this.titulo = obra.getTitulo();
        this.fecha = obra.getFecha();
        this.precioRef = obra.getPrecioRef();
        this.dimensiones = obra.getDimensiones();
    }

    public long getCodigoObra() {
        return codigoObra;
    }

    public void setCodigoObra(long codigoObra) {
        this.codigoObra = codigoObra;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public Calendar getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Calendar fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public float getPrecioRef() {
        return precioRef;
    }

    public void setPrecioRef(float precioRef) {
        this.precioRef = precioRef;
    }

    public String getDimensiones() {
        return dimensiones;
    }

    public void setDimensiones(String dimensiones) {
        this.dimensiones = dimensiones;
    }
    
}

public class Artista {
    private long codigoArtista;
    private long cedula;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private Calendar fechaNac;
    private long telefono;

    public Artista() {
    }

    public Artista(long codigoArtista, long cedula, String nombre, String apellidos, Calendar fechaNac, long telefono) {
        this.codigoArtista = codigoArtista;
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public long getCodigoArtista() {
        return codigoArtista;
    }

    public void setCodigoArtista(long codigoArtista) {
        this.codigoArtista = codigoArtista;
    }

    public long getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(long cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public Calendar getFechaNac() {
        return fechaNac;
    }

    public void setFechaNac(Calendar fechaNac) {
        this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
    }

    public long getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(long telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
    
}

public class Compra {
    private long codigoCompra;
    private Calendar fecha;
    private boolean pagado;

    public Compra() {
    }

    public Compra(long codigoCompra, Calendar fecha, boolean pagado) {
        this.codigoCompra = codigoCompra;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.pagado = pagado;
    }
    
    public Compra(Compra compra){
        this.codigoCompra = compra.getCodigoCompra();
        this.fecha = compra.getFecha();
        this.pagado = compra.isPagado();
    }

    public long getCodigoCompra() {
        return codigoCompra;
    }

    public void setCodigoCompra(long codigoCompra) {
        this.codigoCompra = codigoCompra;
    }

    public Calendar getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Calendar fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public boolean isPagado() {
        return pagado;
    }

    public void setPagado(boolean pagado) {
        this.pagado = pagado;
    }
    
}

public class Cliente {
    private long codigoCliente;
    private long cedula;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String direccion;
    private long telefono;

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public Cliente(long codigoCliente, long cedula, String nombre, String apellidos, String direccion, long telefono) {
        this.codigoCliente = codigoCliente;
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
    
    public Cliente(Cliente cliente){
        this.codigoCliente = cliente.getCodigoCliente();
        this.cedula = cliente.getCedula();
        this.nombre = cliente.getNombre();
        this.apellidos = cliente.getApellidos();
        this.direccion = cliente.getDireccion();
        this.telefono = cliente.getTelefono();
    }

    public long getCodigoCliente() {
        return codigoCliente;
    }

    public void setCodigoCliente(long codigoCliente) {
        this.codigoCliente = codigoCliente;
    }

    public long getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(long cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public long getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(long telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
    
    
}

public class ControlGaleria {
    ArrayList<Obra> listaobras=new ArrayList<Obra>();
    ArrayList<Artista> listaartistas=new ArrayList<Artista>();
    ArrayList<Obra> obraartista=new ArrayList<Obra>();
    ArrayList<Cliente> listaclientes=new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    ArrayList<Compra> listacompras=new ArrayList<Compra>();
    ArrayList<Obra> obracomprada=new ArrayList<Obra>();
    ArrayList<Cliente> comprador=new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    ArrayList<Object> datoscompra=new ArrayList<Object>();
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public void Instancias(){
        GestionObras gestion=new GestionObras();
        listaobras=gestion.AgregarObras();
        listaartistas=gestion.AgregarArtistas();
    }
    
    public void InstanciasCliente(){
        GestionClientes gestioncli=new GestionClientes();
        listaclientes=gestioncli.AgregarClientes();
        
    }
    
    public void VerListaObras(){
        for(Obra obra: listaobras){
            System.out.println("Titulo: "+obra.getTitulo());
            System.out.println("Fecha de creacion: "+obra.getFecha());
            System.out.println("Precio: "+obra.getPrecioRef());
            System.out.println("Dimensiones: "+obra.getDimensiones());
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
    
    public void BuscarObra(String titulo,String nombre){
        Artista artista=new Artista();
        for(Obra obra:listaobras){
            if(titulo==obra.getTitulo()){
                System.out.println("Obra de titulo: "+obra.getTitulo()+" encontrada");
            }
            if(nombre==artista.getNombre()){
                System.out.println("xd");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void InsertarObra(Obra obra){
        long cod;
        int numdigitos;
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese codigo de obra(7 digitos): ");
            cod = scan.nextLong();
            numdigitos = String.valueOf(cod).length();
        } while (isvalid(numdigitos) != true||Existe(cod) != true);
        obra.setCodigoObra(cod);
        System.out.println("Ingrese titulo de la obra: ");
        obra.setTitulo(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Ingrese fecha de la obra: ");
        String fechaString = scan.next();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //Date fecha = sdf.parse(fechaString);
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        //obra.setFecha(calendario.setTime(fecha));
        System.out.println("Ingrese precio de la obra: ");
        obra.setPrecioRef(scan.nextFloat());
        System.out.println("Ingrese dimensiones de la obra: ");
        obra.setDimensiones(scan.next());
        if (!listaobras.contains(obra)) {
            obra = new Obra(obra);
            this.listaobras.add(obra);
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isvalid(int numdigitos){
        boolean valid=numdigitos==7;
        if(valid==false){
            System.out.println("Error, el codigo debe tener 7 digitos");
        }
        return valid;
    }
    public boolean Existe(long cod){
        for (Obra obra : listaobras) {
            boolean valid = (cod != obra.getCodigoObra());
            if (valid == false) {
                System.out.println("Error, el codigo ya existe");
            }
            return valid;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
   /* public void AsignarObraArtista(Obra obra,Artista art){
        for(Artista artista:listaartistas){
                System.out.println("Lista de artistas: ");
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+artista.getNombre()+" "+artista.getApellidos());
                System.out.println("Cedula: "+artista.getCedula()+"\n");
            }
        System.out.println("Su artista se encuentra en la lista?(s/n)");
                char opcion;
                opcion=scan.next().charAt(0);
                if(opcion=='s'){
                    if(listaartistas.contains(artista)&&!listaobras.contains(obra.getCodigoObra())&&listaobras.contains(obra)){
                        obraartista.add(obra);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del artista: ");
                    artista.setNombre(scan.next());
                    System.out.println("Ingrese apellido del artista: ");
                    artista.setApellidos(scan.next());
                    System.out.println("ingrese cedula del artista: ");
                    artista.setCedula(scan.nextInt());
                    System.out.println("Ingrese telefono del artista: ");
                    artista.setTelefono(scan.nextInt());
                    listaartistas.add(artista);
                    if(listaartistas.contains(artista)&&!listaobras.contains(obra.getCodigoObra())&&listaobras.contains(obra)&&!listaobras.contains(obra.getCodigoObra())){
                        obraartista.add(obra);
                    }
                }
    }*/
    
    public void ModificarObra(long codigoObra){
        for(Obra obra:listaobras){
            if(codigoObra==obra.getCodigoObra()){
                int opt;
                do{
                    System.out.println("1.Modificar codigo: "+obra.getCodigoObra());
                    System.out.println("2.Modificar titulo: "+obra.getTitulo());
                    System.out.println("3.Modificar fecha: "+obra.getFecha());
                    System.out.println("4.Modificar precio: "+obra.getPrecioRef());
                    System.out.println("5.Modificar dimensiones: "+obra.getDimensiones());
                    System.out.println("6.Volver al menu principal");
                    System.out.println("Elija una opcion: ");
                    opt=scan.nextInt();
                    switch(opt){
                        case 1:
                            long codigo;
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nuevo codigo:");
                            codigo=scan.nextLong();
                            if(codigo==obra.getCodigoObra()){
                                System.out.println("Este codigo de obra ya existe, no se realizaron cambios.");
                            }
                            else{
                                obra.setCodigoObra(codigo);
                                System.out.println("Codigo modificado");
                            }
                            break;
                            
                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo titulo:");
                            obra.setTitulo(scan.next());
                            System.out.println("Titulo modificado");
                            break;
                            
                        case 3 :
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nueva fecha:");
                            
                            System.out.println("Fecha modificada");
                            break;
                            
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nuevo precio:");
                            obra.setPrecioRef(scan.nextFloat());
                            System.out.println("Precio modificado");
                            break;
                            
                        case 5:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nuevas dimensiones: ");
                            obra.setDimensiones(scan.next());
                            System.out.println("Dimensiones modificadas");
                            break;
                    
                    }
                }while(opt<6);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Obra no encontrada");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void EliminarObra(long codigoObra){
        for(Obra obra:listaobras){
            if(codigoObra==obra.getCodigoObra()){
                listaobras.remove(obra);
                System.out.println("Obra eliminada");
                
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Obra no existente.");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void VerListaClientes(){
        for(Cliente cliente:listaclientes){
            System.out.println("Cedula: "+cliente.getCedula());
            System.out.println("Nombre completo: "+cliente.getNombre()+" "+cliente.getApellidos());
            System.out.println("Direccion: "+cliente.getDireccion());
            System.out.println("Telefono: "+cliente.getTelefono());
        }
    }
    
    public void InsertarCliente(Cliente cliente){
        if(!listaclientes.contains(cliente)){
            cliente=new Cliente(cliente);
            this.listaclientes.add(cliente);
        }
    }
    
    public void ModificarCliente(long codigoCliente){
        for(Cliente cliente:listaclientes){
            if(codigoCliente==cliente.getCodigoCliente()){
                int opt;
                do{
                    System.out.println("1.Modificar codigo: "+cliente.getCodigoCliente());
                    System.out.println("2.Modificar cedula: "+cliente.getCedula());
                    System.out.println("3.Modificar nombre: "+cliente.getNombre());
                    System.out.println("4.Modificar apellidos: "+cliente.getApellidos());
                    System.out.println("5.Modificar direccion: "+cliente.getDireccion());
                    System.out.println("6.Modificar telefono: "+cliente.getTelefono());
                    System.out.println("7.Volver al menu principal");
                    System.out.println("Elija una opcion: ");
                    opt=scan.nextInt();
                    switch(opt){
                        case 1:
                            long codigo;
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nuevo codigo:");
                            codigo=scan.nextLong();
                            if(codigo==cliente.getCodigoCliente()){
                                System.out.println("Este codigo de cliente ya existe, no se realizaron cambios.");
                            }
                            else{
                                cliente.setCodigoCliente(codigo);
                                System.out.println("Codigo modificado");
                            }
                            break;
                            
                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nueva cedula:");
                            cliente.setCedula(scan.nextLong());
                            System.out.println("Cedula modificada");
                            break;
                            
                        case 3 :
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nuevo nombre:");
                            cliente.setNombre(scan.next());
                            System.out.println("Nombre modificado");
                            break;
                            
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nuevo apellido:");
                            cliente.setApellidos(scan.next());
                            System.out.println("Apellido modificado");
                            break;
                            
                        case 5:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nueva direccion: ");
                            cliente.setDireccion(scan.next());
                            System.out.println("Direccion modificada");
                            break;
                            
                        case 6:
                            System.out.println("Ingrese nuevo telefono:");
                            cliente.setTelefono(scan.nextLong());
                            System.out.println("Telefono modificado");
                            break;
                    
                    }
                }while(opt<7);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Cliente no encontrado");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void EliminarCliente(long codigoCliente){
        for(Cliente cliente:listaclientes){
            if(codigoCliente==cliente.getCodigoCliente()){
                listaclientes.remove(cliente);
                System.out.println("Cliente eliminada");
                
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Cliente no existente.");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void ComprarObra(long codigoObra,long codigoCliente,Compra compra,Obra ob,Cliente cliente){
        char op;
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese codigo del cliente: ");
            codigoCliente = scan.nextLong();
        }while(ClienteValido(codigoCliente)!=true);
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese codigo de la obra: ");
            codigoObra=scan.nextLong();
        }while(NoExiste(codigoObra)!=true);
        for(Obra obra:listaobras){
            if(codigoObra==obra.getCodigoObra()){
                System.out.println("Titulo de la obra: "+obra.getTitulo());
                System.out.println("Precio de la obra: "+obra.getPrecioRef());
                
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
            System.out.println("Desea comprar esta obra?(s/n)");
            op = scan.next().charAt(0);
            if (op == 's') {
                Random random = new Random();
                int r=random.nextInt(9999999);
                if(!listacompras.contains(compra.getCodigoCompra())){
                    compra.setCodigoCompra(r);
                }
                System.out.println("Codigo de compra: " + compra.getCodigoCompra());
                compra.setPagado(true);
                if (!listacompras.contains(compra)) {
                    compra = new Compra(compra);
                    this.listacompras.add(compra);
                    this.datoscompra.add(compra);
                    this.datoscompra.add(cliente);
                    this.datoscompra.add(ob);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Compra cancelada");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void AsignarACompra(Compra comp,Obra obra,Cliente cliente){
        for(Compra compra:listacompras){
            if(listacompras.contains(compra)&&!listaobras.contains(obra.getCodigoObra())&&listaobras.contains(obra)){
                obracomprada.add(obra);
            }
        }
        for(Compra compra:listacompras){
            if(listacompras.contains(compra)&&!listaclientes.contains(cliente.getCodigoCliente())&&listaclientes.contains(cliente)){
                comprador.add(cliente);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void VerListaCompras(){
        for(Compra compra:listacompras){
            System.out.println("Codigo de compra: "+compra.getCodigoCompra());
            System.out.println("Fecha de la compra: "+compra.getFecha());
            for(Obra ob:obracomprada){
                System.out.println("Codigo de la obra: "+ob.getCodigoObra());
            System.out.println("Titulo: "+ob.getTitulo());
            }
            for(Cliente cli:comprador){
                System.out.println("Codigo del cliente: "+cli.getCodigoCliente());
            System.out.println("Nombre del cliente: "+cli.getNombre());
            System.out.println("Cedula del cliente: "+cli.getCedula());
            }
            
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
            

    }
    public boolean ClienteValido(long codigoCliente){
        for (Cliente cliente : listaclientes) {
            boolean valid=false;
            if (codigoCliente == cliente.getCodigoCliente()) {
                valid = true; 
                return valid;
            }
            if (valid == false) {
                    System.out.println("Cliente no existe");
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean NoExiste(long codigoObra){
        for (Obra obra : listaobras) {
            boolean valid=false;
            if (codigoObra == obra.getCodigoObra()) {
                valid = true;
                return valid;
            }  
            if (valid == false) {
                    System.out.println("La obra no existe");
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean CodigoCompra(int r){
        for(Compra compra:listacompras){
            boolean valid=(r!=compra.getCodigoCompra());
            return valid;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public ArrayList<Obra> getListaobras() {
        return listaobras;
    }

    public void setListaobras(ArrayList<Obra> listaobras) {
        this.listaobras = listaobras;
    }
    
}
```

Pero creo que esto no ha funcionado porque ademas luego debo imprimir una lista de las compras hechas mostrando los codigos de las compras, los datos de los clientes y de las obras.

Basicamente no he sabido asignar una clase o sus datos a otra.

¿Como podria hacer esta asignacion? Me está comiendo la cabeza esto. No puedo poner atributos de tipo clase en las otras clases, todo lo debo hacer en la clase controladorGaleria que es la ultima clase que esta ahi.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pon las clases para ver como lo estas haciendo si solo pones el main esta jodio

Comment: @unknow Ya las puse.